# How to know whether to use dot notation or simply insert something as an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, methods, arguments

For example, we have two functions, `len()` and `title()`. Why do some functions/methods, in this case `len()`, requires us to use an argument in order for it to do its job, while some other functions/methods require us to use dot notation to do its job, in this case, `title()`.

Comment: `len` is a built-in function (I hope you are not overwriting it with a custom function), what is `title`

Comment: `title` is also built in, its to make a character of a string upper case. These functions/methods are just used as examples though

Comment: `title` is not a built-in function in python it is a string method

Comment: `len` is not a method, it is a function, hence, you do not access it through an object (like a method, e.g. `"foo".title()`. The way to know is by reading the documentation

Comment: Basically it is a design decision of the code authors. Especially for "len" I personally think it is questionable but it is as it is.

Comment: By reading the documentation.

Comment: More precisely, `len` is a variable with a function value. `str.title` is an attribute access that returns a function, and `"foo".title` is an attribute access that returns a `method` object. All three values are callable, hence `len("foo") == 3`, `str.title("foo") == "Foo"`, and `"foo".title() == "Foo"`. (Don't worry  about`str.title("foo")`; it's a valid expression, but you virtually never call an instance method like this.)

Comment: Well, `__len__`, a method, exists and is called when using `len`, a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.function(args)` is a method. `function(args)` is a function.

A method is called on an `object`, and a function is simply, well, a function.

A function can be called by itself, but a method needs an `object`.

Answer (score 0):

One of them is a method inherited from the class of the instance, other one is a built-in function globally available.

You need to understand inheritance in programming to fully grasp this. I would recommend studying object oriented programming.

Comment: currently am, this detail was not told though

Comment: I was just using those 2 functions/methods as examples

Answer (score -1):

As someone who embarked in this path not so long ago, I can relate to your question, as I asked similar questions as well.

IMO there is no set in stone way to know, this is a concept that you will understand more and more as you learn different methods/functions.

It's very similar to understanding masculine/feminine connotations of stuff in a new language.